# How to align text in UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Is it possible to align `placeholder` in the middle of a `UITextField`? And when we start editing it should it start from left corner of `UITextField`? I am new to iOS.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the sample code for that.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    txtList.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
}
// This method is called once we click inside the textField
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    txtList.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
}
```

Don't forgot to give delegate of `UITextField`.

Answer (score 2):

Start by setting `textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter`. Your best bet is to implement the use of the UITextFieldDelegate protocol to know when the user is tapping inside your text field. Once the user has tapped inside your text field change the property to `textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft` if you want the alignment to go back to the left. Additionally, using the same protocol, when the user taps out or the focus leaves your text field, set the property back to `textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter`.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3.0 ... Swift 5.5

```
    textField.textAlignment = .center
```

Comment: FYI: It still works (of course), because it has nothing to do with the Swift version; it's related to iOS version and it will probably be supported by UIKit forever.